# Downvoted an answer, undid the downvote, got badge and still says one downvote. Is this a bug or by design?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, down-votes

My sequence of steps:

> 1. Downvoted an answer.
> 2. Saw I lost one rep.
> 3. Decided to undo my downvote.
> 4. Got Critic Badge, and 1 downvote in my history
> 5. Did not lose rep (got one rep back).

So I've technically cast a downvote, but I didn't lose rep from it since it was undone, and the downvote did not stay on the question. It was a while ago, but I think I undid it because I decided I wanted to make it to 50 rep sooner so I could start commenting.

Can someone confirm that:

> 1. this a bug or a feature.
> 2. this still happens.
> 3. I'm not crazy and I don't have a downvote hiding somewhere?

Comment: By design. You don't lose a badge once you gain it.

Comment: Is it still in your history, though, or is that another downvote?

Comment: As far as I know that's the same one minitech

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> this a bug or a feature.

Feature - typically, except in cases of fraud, badges are not reversed.  You downvoted, got the badge and then reversed the downvote and got your rep back but kept the badge since you did downvote.

> this still happens.

Yes - it will happen anything someone downvotes and undownvotes right away on their first downvote. (it will happen without the badge award anytime)

> I'm not crazy and I don't have a downvote hiding somewhere?

No - you aren't crazy (at least any more than normal)

Comment: **+1** for "at least any more than normal".

Comment: What about the downvote in my history? I'm 99% sure that's the same one. Is that a bug or a feature?

Comment: @Matt do you mean under "Votes Cast" in the summary tab?  Since that's the only record of your voting history I have access to, but I believe that might record all of your activity whether it is current or not.

Comment: @Matt It is just a guess though, based on 2 facts, first based on what you said in this question about earning the critic badge after the undone downvote, and 2nd that same field for me is about 3x my recorded downvotes under the "voting" tab of my profile and that tab only shows current downvotes after deletions and reversed votes. See yous http://stackoverflow.com/users/2534803/matt?tab=votes&sort=downvote

Comment: Looking at my votes page, it does confirm I have zero downvotes. Interesting thanks psubsee2003!